# Difference between two types of class properties definition?

Tags: python, class

Is there a difference between

```
class Foo(object):
    bar = 1
    def __init__(self):
        ... etc.
```

and

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
       ... etc.

Foo.bar = 1
```

In both cases `bar` is a property of the class and it is same for all instances of the class, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that the only difference is that in the second case, `Foo.bar` doesn't exist until the `Foo.bar = 1` statement is executed while in the first case is already available when the class object is created.

That's probably a small difference without any effect in your code (unless there is some code that requires `Foo.bar` before it's available in the second case). However, I'd say that the first option is better in terms of readability since you don't have to scroll down to know the attributes for your class, they're already there.

Answer (score 4):

If you're writing your own code, go with:

```
class Foo(object):
    bar = 1
```

Becase this version:

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

Foo.bar = 1
```

Even though it's legit

1. Looks more like a hack.
2. Is less readable in most cases.
3. You might have problems if you try to access the `bar` attribute before its been created:

   ```
   >>> class Foo:
   ...     pass
   ... 
   >>> f = Foo()
   >>> f.bar
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'bar'
   >>> Foo.bar = 1
   >>> f.bar   # but hey, now you're ok!
   1
   ```

Other than that I don't see many differences.

Answer (score -1):

Both versions are the same (see transcript of tests at end of this answer), but note that (a) in neither case is `bar` the same for all instances of `Foo`.

At the moment an instance is created, reading `bar` on the instance will read the value in `Foo`, and assignments to `Foo.bar` will be reflected in the instance *until `instance.bar` is assigned to.* At that moment of assignment, the instance gets its own `__dict__` entry, which is entirely independant of the class.

```
In [62]: class Foo: pass

In [63]: Foo.bar = 1

In [64]: Foo.bar
Out[64]: 1

In [65]: f = Foo()

In [66]: f.bar
Out[66]: 1

In [67]: f.bar +=1

In [68]: f.bar
Out[68]: 2

In [69]: Foo.bar
Out[69]: 1

In [70]: Foo.bar +=3

In [71]: Foo.bar
Out[71]: 4

In [72]: g = Foo()

In [73]: g.bar
Out[73]: 4

In [74]: class Qux: bar = 1

In [75]: Qux.bar
Out[75]: 1

In [76]: q = Qux()

In [77]: q.bar
Out[77]: 1

In [78]: q.bar+=1

In [79]: q.bar
Out[79]: 2

In [80]: Qux.bar
Out[80]: 1

In [81]: Qux.bar +=1

In [82]: r = Qux()

In [83]: r.bar
Out[83]: 2

In [84]: q.bar
Out[84]: 2

In [85]: s = Qux()

In [87]: s.__dict__
Out[87]: {}

In [88]: q.__dict__
Out[88]: {'bar': 2}

In [89]: Qux.bar = 'foo'

In [90]: Qux.bar
Out[90]: 'foo'

In [91]: s.bar
Out[91]: 'foo'
```

Comment: -1 for being plain wrong: instanes of "Foo" are not aasigned copies of "bar" - they access the class attribute. When aninstance attribute is set, it gets its own attribute. See my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302789/changing-variables-in-multiple-python-instances/9304924#9304924

Comment: @jsbueno: Prove it. The behaviour looks exactly like each instance getting a copy of the value in the class object (which is a pointer to an object).

Comment: @jsbueno: I've added my own evidence, given that the answer you link to does not in fact have any evidence for your position.

Comment: -1 because @jsbueno was right and the proof is that you fixed the answer without even saying "thank you".

Comment: @jcollado: I don't just roll over and change my answer when someone tells me I'm wrong with no evidence whatsoever. Just saying "you're wrong" with no evidence has no value whatsoever.

Comment: You fixed the answer - but I am keeping the downvote due to your unwinligness to be polite, or aknowledge you where wrong. "Prove it"is just childish. "class A(object):\n\tb=0\na = A()\nb = A()\n;a.b is b.b\na.b='anything'\na.b is b.b" will just show you what happens, but you can't demand "prove it" for a comment.

Comment: @jsbueno Of course I can demand proof for a comment, and I'd be a fool not to. Since when is it childish to ask someone to back up their claims?