# Changing Variables in Multiple Java Instances

Tags: java, class

Essentially I'm trying to do something that is stated here [Changing variables in multiple Python instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302789/changing-variables-in-multiple-python-instances) 
but in java.

I want to reset a variable in all instances of a certain class so something like:

```
public class NewClass{
int variable = 1;
}
```

then:

```
NewClass one = new NewClass();
NewClass two = new NewClass();
NewClass three = new NewClass();

Newclass.variable = 2;

System.out.println(one.variable);
System.out.println(two.variable);
System.out.println(three.variable);
```

output would be:

```
2
2
2
```

is there a way to do that?

Comment: Should value of `variable` *always* be the same for each instance? If yes then you can make that variable `static` via `static int variable = 1;` which would mean it doesn't belong to instances but to class.

Comment: Just make the field `static`. But this seems pretty much like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use static variable

```
public class NewClass{
    static int variable = 1;
}
```

Important facts about static variable, please check

1. If the value of a variable is not varied from object to object such 
   type of variables is not recommended to declare as instance variables. 
   We have to declare such type of variables at class level by using 
   static modifier.
2. In the case of instance variables for every object a separate copy will 
   be created but in the case of static variables for entire class only 
   one copy will be created and shared by every object of that class.
3. Static variables will be crated at the time of class loading and 
   destroyed at the time of class unloading hence the scope of the static 
   variable is exactly same as the scope of the .class file.
4. Static variables will be stored in method area. Static variables should 
   be declared with in the class directly but outside of any method or 
   block or constructor.
5. Static variables can be accessed from both instance and static areas 
   directly.
6. We can access static variables either by class name or by object 
   reference but usage of class name is recommended.
   But within the same class it is not required to use class name we can 
   access directly.

Answer (score 0):

Make that variable [static so that it is now a property of the class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) and not an instance.

```
public class NewClass{
  static int variable = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark the attribute static.

```java
public class NewClass {
static int variable = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

java does not support multiple instance...but you csn solve this problem using
interface. ex. public interface abc